# print screen using angular5 unable to get values in it

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

Here Im trying to get the values in the print screen, but Im getting the empty values **which I have attached below screenshot** . All I want to get values in the print screen, Or is any modules for it

this is my component.ts file

```
  printDiv() {
    const divContents = document.getElementById('dvContents').innerHTML;
    const printWindow = window.open('', '');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Process Compensation Report</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body style="color: black">');
    printWindow.document.write(divContents);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    printWindow.print();
  }
```

here html files

```
<section id="dvContents" style="color: white;" class="form_cont">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row mt-20">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 text-right res-tleft">
                    <label>Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" > **// this is not printing**
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" *ngIf="arcButt">
                    <button class="btn btn-gradient-txt" type="button" (click)="archiveButt();">
                        <span style="font-size: 14px">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-archive-o"></i> Archive</span>
                    </button>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

here the screenshot of the pic, here Im getting the print but with empty input box.
 **ScreenShot** 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't (directly) angular. The problem is that you are reading the `innerHtml` which will only provide you the information the `innerHtml` can give - those being the values of the **attributes** defined on the tags.

Let me explain. Suppose you have the following html (forget about angular for now):

```
<input type="text" value="42" >
```

This is an input filed, type "text". On it we have applied an attribute.

```
value="42"
```

Now, you assumed that changing the value of the input field would change the value of the attribute - perhaps you though they were the same. This is a common error: actually, the (value) property of the object (the element node) is one thing and the (value) attribute is another. They are obviously related, but not the same.

Maybe an example can make this clearer:

```
element.value = "42"
```

This would set the "value" **property** of the element to "42". The attribute value is not affected.  The following instead would set the value of the **attribute** to "42"

```
element.setAttribute("value", "42")
```

Now, most browsers will probably detect a change in the value **attribute** on the DOM and change the value **property** on the actual element accordingly, but they are still separate identities.

> ***Taken from [Angular - HTML attribute vs. DOM property](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#html-attribute-vs-dom-property)***:
>
> For example, when the browser renders `<input type="text" value="Bob">`, it creates a corresponding DOM node with a value property initialized to "Bob".
>
> When the user enters "Sally" into the input box, the DOM element value property becomes "Sally". But the HTML value attribute remains unchanged as you discover if you ask the input element about that attribute: `input.getAttribute('value')` returns "Bob".

As a proof, please consider the following sample - which doesn't even use angular:

```js
function showInnerHtml() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('questionField').innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="questionField">
  <input id="questionField" type="text" value="420">
  <button type="button" onClick="showInnerHtml()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Try and change the value in the input field, then press the button. You will see that the value on the attribute does not reflect your change - only the property does.

So, what you are trying to do is not possible by itself.

That said, if you really have to, there is a possible (unwarranted to work on every browser) workaround.
Angular can use a special [attr.name] syntax to bind to an attribute value. That means that you can actually create a binding to the HTML attribute value property.

Please, [refer to this stackblitz for a quick POC of this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hfc6zu), and feel free to ask for more clarifications if needed.

Comment: tq @SPArchaeologist. It work exactly How I need to it . I have done in this way [attr.property]="value" i.e, [att.value]="name".